# Why is a scroll bar appearing even when overflow-y: visible is set?

Tags: css

When applying the properties overflow-x: auto; and overflow-y: visible;, scroll bars appear on the y-axis as well. Is there a solution for this?

I want to display a scroll bar only on the x-axis, but there is an issue where a scroll bar appears when the length on the y-axis increases.

Comment: That's how `visible` works. You can hide the scrollbar by setting `overflow-y: hidden`

Comment: Overflow values come in two "flavours": {visible, clip} & {auto, scroll, hidden}. You can only mix axes within a flavour, not one of each. When you try, "visible" becomes "auto" and "clip" becomes "hidden".

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `overflow-y: visible` that's why it's visible, if you don't want it, type `hidden` instead

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto hidden; /* Show scroll bars only when needed, hide it on the y-axis */
}
```